# Jest & Enzyme: Mocking a function (which contains xhr requests and also sets states) that resides inside of another function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, jestjs

### using jest and enzyme, I'm trying test the change of state when handleUploadClick() is called and consequently triggers uploadFile().

```
handleUploadClick = () => {
        if (this.props.onUploadClick) {
          this.props.onUploadClick();
        }

        this.uploadFile(this.state.selectedFile, this.state.apiFieldName, (progress) => {
          this.setState({ uploadProgress: progress, buttonState: '', errorMessage: '' });
        });
      };
uploadFile(file, apiFieldName, progressCallback) {
    if (file) {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      const formData = new FormData();
      const fileItem = {};
      fileItem[apiFieldName] = file;
      xhr.responseType = 'json';
      formData.append(apiFieldName, fileItem[apiFieldName]);

      xhr.onload = () => {
        const returnObj = xhr.response;
        if (xhr.status === 500) {
          this.setState({ errorMessage: 'There was a problem processing the upload. ' +
          'Please select a different file' });
          this.setState({ buttonState: 'error' });
        } else if (xhr.status === 400) {
          this.setState({ errorMessage: 'There was a problem uploading the file to the server' });
          this.setState({ buttonState: 'error' });
        } else {
          this.props.onCompletedUpload(returnObj);
          progressCallback(100);
        }
      };

      xhr.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
          progressCallback(Math.round(((e.loaded / e.total)) * 100));
        }
      };
      xhr.open(this.props.method, this.props.url, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `JWT ${this.props.token}`);
      xhr.send(formData);
      this.xhrs[file.index] = xhr;
    }
  }
```

---

So far, I've been able to use an instance of my component ( wrapper.instance() ) to spy on uploadFile

```
const instance = wrapper.instance();
const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'uploadFile');
```

---

But this doesn't account for the state change that occurs.

---

Here is my full test

```
it(' handleUploadClick prop should call onUploadClick and uploadFile', () => {
      const blob = new Blob(['totally legit scan'], { type: 'text/plain' });
      const name = 'scan.zip';
      wrapper.setState({ selectedFile: blob, apiFieldName: name });
      const instance = wrapper.instance();
      const spy = jest.spyOn(instance, 'uploadFile');
      wrapper.instance().handleUploadClick();
      expect(props.onUploadClick).toBeCalled();
      expect(spy).toBeCalled();
    });
```

---

I want to check that buttonState, errorMessage, and uploadProgress are getting set. What do I need to mock and then test to make that possible?

```
expect(wrapper.state.buttonState).toEqual('')
expect(wrapper.state.errorMessage).toEqual('')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I think it's great that you want to write tests for your code. Enzyme and jest are really helpful tools, so you're on a good track.

Tests can be simpler if you only test one function at a time. For example, the test for `handleUploadClick` need only ensure that `uploadFile` is called, which your spy is already doing.

Testing `uploadFile()` would then be in another test. For this you will need to mock `XMLHTTPRequest`, since testing `XMLHTTPRequest` is probably not your goal - you just want to test your own code. This will be cleaner if you break the `XMLHTTPRequest`-calling code out into its own function.

I would break this up as follows:

1. 2-3 functions that create and configure the httprequest
2. 3-4 functions that handle the results of the httprequest

Those you can test separately pretty easily.

For 1, mock `XMLHTTPRequest` so that you're only testing your own code. Don't involve a real `XMLHTTPRequest` at all.

For 2, one option is to create your own js objects with the response and status you want to test with, and mock `setState` and `this.props` if needed.

### Separating view from logic

Alternatively, and this is what I would do, change `errorMessage` and `buttonStatus` to properties of this React class. Wrap this view component in a logical component. Instead of calling `setState` in this component, modify the props passed in by the wrapper. Separating view from logic will make it more obvious how to test things. There are various ways to do this; my first choice would be to use the React-Redux framework, but there are probably other options with a shorter learning curve.

I found this post about separating logic from views to be helpful: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/3bjdoe/state_is_an_antipattern/ .

### Test First

If you write the test first before you write the code, you'll end up with better separation of concerns.